# How to document command-line which requires one of two options?

Tags: command-line, documentation

I'm familiar how to specify optional and required command-line parameters e.g:

```
MyApp <inputPath> [logging]
```

But what if the user has to specify exactly one of two (or more) options, e.g. they *must* either specify `numRepetitions=<num-reps>` or `stopTime=<stop-time>`? How would this be documented in an unambiguous way?

Answer (score 4):

Use `{}` curly brackets.

```
{ Learn by [an | the | next [self-explanatory]] example }
```

Learn by next self-explanatory example:

```
=>prompt $Q$G

=>taskkill
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Neither /FI nor /PID nor /IM were specified.
Type "TASKKILL /?" for usage.

=>taskkill /?

TASKKILL [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]]
         { [/FI filter] [/PID processid | /IM imagename] } [/T] [/F]
```

**[Command-Line Syntax Key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771080.aspx)**

- `Notation                       ​​` *Description*
- `Text without brackets or braces​​` Items you must type as shown
- `<Text inside angle brackets>   ​​` Placeholder for which you must supply a value
- `[Text inside square brackets]  ​​` Optional items
- `{Text inside braces}           ​​` Set of required items; choose one
- `Vertical bar (|)               ​​` Separator for mutually exclusive items; choose one
- `Ellipsis (…)                   ​​` Items that can be repeated